# Clang fails with "static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression" for a static constexpr method of an object within another class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, g++, clang

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, size_t CAPACITY>
class Container {
    std::vector<T> storage;
  public:
    static constexpr auto capacity() {
        return CAPACITY;
    }
    ///Some methods where CAPACITY is used
};

class Dummy {
    Container<int, 5> container;
    void dummy() {
        static_assert(container.capacity(), "Does not compile"); ///<===Fails with Clang
        static_assert(decltype(container)::capacity(), "Compiles");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Container<int, 5> container;
    static_assert(container.capacity(), "Compiles");
    static_assert(decltype(container)::capacity(), "Compiles");
}
```

It compiles fine with gcc (See [test](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fac9fc4d9248f787))

On clang the first static assert instead gives (See [test](https://rextester.com/DRY39335)):

> ```
> error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
>         static_assert(container.capacity(), "Does not compile");
>                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>  note: implicit use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function
> ```

Which compiler is right? Why is that line of coding failing? Why does it fail only when the object `container` is declared within a class method and it succeeds in `main()`? Is the `decltype` version the only alternative?

---

Here is a reduced sample that allows to reproduce the problem (thanks to Frank, [see it in action](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bqPx411qf))

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    static constexpr auto capacity() {
        return 12;
    }
};

class Dummy {
    Foo container;
    void dummy() {
        static_assert(container.capacity(), "Does not compile"); ///<===Fails with Clang
        static_assert(decltype(container)::capacity(), "Compiles");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo container;
    static_assert(container.capacity(), "Compiles");
    static_assert(decltype(container)::capacity(), "Compiles");
}
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to side with clang here on account of http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#footnote-53: "the subexpression evaluation happens even if the result is unnecessary to determine the value of the entire postfix expression, for example if the id-expression denotes a static member."

Comment: As far as rewording goes, how about: "Is Clang correct in refusing to access static constexpr properties of members by their identifier?". Also, FWIW, templates have nothing to do with it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a43G1sWY5